# How to create comma separated list from array and return as json enode array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create JSON from a comma delimited string.Now my code is like this

```
 $sql="select Pri_name from nri_privilege";
 $getvalue=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
 while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getvalue))
 {
      $getallresults[]=$result;
 }
 foreach($getallresults as $rereult)
 {       
    print_r($rereult);
    name =$rereult['Pri_name'];
    name .=$name .',';
    //echo $name;
    //echo json_encode($name);
 }
```

I am fetching data from database and loop it inside a foreach. How to create JSON from a comma delimited string?

Comment: how you want your output to look like

Comment: which type of data you are getting from array. any example?

Comment: Just `json_encode()` the `$getallresults` variable instead of making it into a string. However, as you wish - `expode()` the string and then `json_encode()` it, check the docs for explode [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: Why would you first want to create a comma separated string only to `explode()` it afterwards? Why not simply `json_encode()` the array you already have?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the title of your post this would do what you described.

```
$array = ["foo", "bar", "bat"]; //some array form e.g. db
$glued = implode(",", $array); //implode it with ,
$json  = json_encode($glued); //and json encode it
```

What I think you really want is this:

```
$array = ["foo", "bar", "bat"]; //some array form e.g. db
$json  = json_encode($array); //json encode the array without step 2.
```

Guess you want to send the `json` encoded array over the wire to somewhere else. In this case no need for any `implode` or `explode`.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
$sql="select Pri_name from nri_privilege";
$getvalue=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getvalue))
{
  $getallresults[]=$result['Pri_name'];
}

echo json_encode($getallresults);
```

Answer (score -1):

You better not append `,` manually. Try this,

```
$names = array();
foreach($getallresults as $rereult){
    $names[] = $rereult['Pri_name'];
}
```

then,

`$comma_seperated_list = implode(", ", names);`

If you want the above string to be json encoded,

`json_encode($comma_seperated_list);`

Otherwise you could encode the whole name array like,

`json_encode($names);`

Hope this helps you!